# How to Append List in Python by reading csv file

Tags: python-3.x, list, opencsv

I am trying to write a simple program that should give the following output when it reads csv file which contains several email ids.

```
email_id = ['emailid1@xyz.com','emailid2@xyz.com','emailid3@xyz.com'] #required format
```

but the problem is the output I got is like this following:

```
[['emailid1@xyz.com']]
[['emailid1@xyz.com'], ['emailid2@xyz.com']]
[['emailid1@xyz.com'], ['emailid2@xyz.com'], ['emailid3@xyz.com']] #getting this wrong format
```

here is my piece of code that I have written: **Kindly suggest me the correction in the following piece of code which would give me the required format**. Thanks in advance.

```
import csv

email_id = []

with open('contacts1.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter = ',')
    for row in reader:
        email_id.append(row)
        print(email_id)
```

**NB.: Note my csv contains only one column that has email ids and has no header.** I also tried the `email_id.extend(row)` but It did not work also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your `print` outside the loop:

```
with open('contacts1.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter = ',')
    for row in reader:
        email_id.append(row)
    print(sum(email_id, []))
```

The loop can also be like this (if you only need one column from the csv):

```
for row in reader:
    email_id.append(row[0])
print(email_id)
```